# Docker: Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tk module) on Linux

Tags: docker, perl, ubuntu, x11

I am trying to run a simple perl gui made using Tk module on a ubuntu:16.04 container using both perl:latest and activestate/circleci-activeperl:latest images.

I get error `Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Tk module)`

What is the command to install the Tk module on the Linux container environment for perl?

I have used cpan to install Tk as below

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install Tk
```

I get the below error
[image]

Comment: On docker, you don't have X11 for this. See error message

Comment: Running interactive GUI images in Docker is tricky and pretty platform-dependent (if you're on a native-Linux host then you at least have X).  I'd suggest just running this directly on your host.

Comment: Installing the Perl Tk module from source requires the Tk library and the corresponding header (`.h`) files. Your package appears to have separated the library and the header files into separate packages (a common practice), and you don't seem to have the package with the header files installed. (You'd need to installing the package that provides these.) But since you're installing for the system Perl, you're better off using the system's package manager to install the module itself (as your answer suggests)

Answer (score 6):

```
apt-get install perl-tk
```

helped in installation of perl-tk module.

Comment: I have edited the command because I think there was a mistake. If that was really meant for, please apologize me and rollback the edit.

Comment: The command with RUN statement was added that way because it was meant to be a part of Dockerfile. If the installation is outside dockerfile then ur edit is correct.

Comment: on Fedora: `sudo dnf install perl-Tk`

Comment: on OpenSuse: `sudo zypper install perl-Tk`